# CSS selector - target only first <a> on page

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to figure out how to target only the first  that resides within a  on one of my pages...

Maybe I am doing something wrong, looking for help.

```
<div id="mem-tools">
  <div class="members">
      <a href="#">Link One</a>
      <a href="#">Link Two</a>  
  </div>
</div>
```

In my CSS, I have the following code:

```
#mem-tools a{
    padding:15px 0 0 65px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#444444;
    font-size:14px;
    height:35px;
    display:block;
}
```

however, I only want the first  to be styled this way, and not the second  within the .members class

From what I understand psuedo classes do not work for IE, so I an not use :nth selector.

Can I define the first  only, to use the above noted style?

Am I over complicating this?

Answer (score 2):

The :first-child would work, but if you don't want to use pseudos can also create a class to style the element... might be eaiser:

```
<div id="mem-tools">
  <div class="members">
    <a href="#" class="first-link">Link One</a>
    <a href="#">Link Two</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can style the class accordingly:

```
#mem-tools a.first-link{
  padding:15px 0 0 65px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#444444;
  font-size:14px;
  height:35px;
  display:block;
}
```

That way you can avoid pseudos.

Comment: Actually there are other reasons to avoid pseudos other then just for older browsers.  Large sites really do worry about [performance](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-selector-performance/) those are some of the worse offenders.  Along with that you definitely can remove the "a" and might even remove the ID also.  `.first-link{...}` would be nice (but I recommend looking into OOCSS if you are getting crazy about it).

Answer (score 1):

`#mem-tools a:first-child` might do the trick

Answer (score -2):

```
.mem-tools +a {
/*
 try your Styles here
*/
}
```

Comment: That selects an `a` that comes after `.mem-tools`, not within it.